# xcode-Token login keychain blocking app build process

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, keychain

Recently, my mac has started prompting me for the "**login**" keychain password in order to build or deploy my app to a device. The build process is stopped at "**Copying Swift standard libraries**". The dialog box says:

Codesign wants to access key "**access**" in your keychain. 
To allow this, enter the "**login**" keychain password.

Inspecting the keychain access application shows the "**login**" keychain is linked to the apple ID I sign into in xcode, which makes perfect sense. The only problem is the password isn't accepted. I've deleted the login keychain, removed the account from xcode entirely, and logged in again, thereby restoring login keychain, but it still prompts me for the login keychain password. This is sadly not the system login password.

When I look in the keychain directory I do not see the login keychain, which seems strange to me. Should I see it? Or is it in the xcode directory? (Haven't looked).

I'm going to try restore OS X as per another threads suggestion but I am not all that hopeful. If anyone could give me a hint as to why this might be happening I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue but in my case i used administrative username and password of my system and it worked for me. Please try to use administrative account credential to for codesign-in.

Comment: I am not prompted for the username, but the password of the account I am logged into and the administrator are the same, so sadly this won't work as far as getting past the dialog box prompting me for "the "login" keychain password"

Comment: did that prompt have options like allow once or allow always